# What does [私ったら] mean?

Tags: meaning, definitions

Is it conditional like the same as saying 「なら」?

Answer (score 4):

This `ったら` is not really a conditional in the way `なら` is, although it does look like etymologically it came from the conditional `たら`. In terms of meaning, it's used to gently express a combination of mild surprise and embarrassment or criticism. See [here](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A3%E3%81%9F%E3%82%89-571733) (in Japanese).

There's a fairly good explanation here on [HiNative](https://hinative.com/ja/questions/5713760), but basically `私ったら` is expressing mild surprise/shame at one's own actions. You might think of it as the `Oh my` in  `Oh my, what a klutz I am`. Like English's `Oh my`, it's not used much in actual conversation.

That said, it's hard to say anything with 100% certainty without context.